# Setting the color \plauthorhl argument inserts space

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-publist

I am trying to customize the highlighting of publist author but unnecessary space is inserted

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    
@article{salem2023implementation,
    title={An implementation of an enhanced DG primary control equipped with fault detection scheme},
    author={Salem, Qusay and Aljarrah, Rafat and Alzaareer, Khaled and Harasis, Salman and Aldaoudeyeh, {Al-Motasem} Ihssan},
    journal={International Journal of Sustainable Energy},
    volume={42},
    number={1},
    pages={318--330},
    year={2023},
    month={3},
    publisher={Taylor \& Francis},
    doi={https://doi.org/10.1080/14786451.2023.2191149}
}
    
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage[bibstyle=publist, plauthorhandling=highlight]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\plauthorname[{Al-Motasem} Ihssan]{Aldaoudeyeh}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\plauthorhl}{m}{%
    \leavevmode\color{DodgerBlue3}%
    \mkbibbold{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
    
    \nocite{*}

    \printbibliography[heading={subbibliography}, title={Journal Articles}, type=article]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where the problem is, but

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\plauthorhl}{m}{%
  \mkbibbold{\color{DodgerBlue3}#1\unskip}%
}
```

avoids the spurious space.

[image]

Comment: the color whatsit interferes with the punctuation tracker, with luacolor it would work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's what I thought.